# How to make a Minecraft door in python on Minecraft Raspberry Pi edition

Tags: python, minecraft

I have tried many times placing a door but all that seems to appear is the bottom half. How do I get the top half?

My python code is:

```
mc.setBlocks (10,11,16,10,10,16,64)
```

Comment: General programming questions belong on our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: this is specific to the raspberry pi version of minecraft as it has a dedicated api that us not available on any other platform. Is this the right site?

Comment: All apologies -- I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do it in two commands:

```
mc.setBlock(x, y, z, 64, 0)
mc.setBlock(x, y+1, z, 64, 8)
```

So, using your numbers, you would need:

```
mc.setBlock(10, 10, 16, 64, 0)
mc.setBlock(10, 11, 16, 64, 8)
```

Also, note that the sub-type for the blocks don't work if you use the named block types.  So, for example, this won't work:

```
mc.setBlock(x, y, z, block.DOOR_WOOD, 0)
mc.setBlock(x, y+1, z, block.DOOR_WOOD, 8) #The 8 will be ignored
```

Although it's not documented anywhere, I assume that there are 8 states for the bottom of the door (0 - 7) corresponding to 4 directions closed and 4 directions opened.  Then add 8 to the get the same direction for the top half of the door (8 - 15).

You can do something similar for other two part objects like beds.

Comment: It took a while to get back to this, but i confirmed it last night - spot on.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the "8" will be ignored is that technically the setBlock() function takes a block id as the fourth argument (not a block). So if your fourth argument was block.DOOR_WOOD.id then the "8" will work.

As it is, by supplying the block type (rather than just its "id") means that Python takes the other attributes from the block and uses them as arguments - thus always using the default "0" for the "data" argument.

HTH.
(NB: This /really/ confused me at first).

Answer (score 0):

## Left wood door close

mc.setBlock(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 64, 1)
mc.setBlock(pos.x, pos.y+1, pos.z, 64, 9)

## Right wood door close

mc.setBlock(pos.x + 1, pos.y, pos.z, 64, 6)
mc.setBlock(pos.x + 1, pos.y+1, pos.z, 64, 13)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).